# How can i parse a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I am sending a string via the serial connection to the python in the following format

```
&5:420:0:03713031464@
```

Which would be parsed as:

```
(start byte) (data length) : (type of message) (priority) (data1) : (data2): (data3) (CRC) (end byte)
```

How would I parse these values? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do? "I mean parse these values", what is your expectation for parsed result?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Regular Expression and how it works. Using regular expression you can define search patterns that you search for in a string. For example the regexp search pattern `\&(\d):(\d)` will search you string for a `&` + a number (storing it in the first group) + `:` + another number 8storing it in the second group). When using it on your string it will store the first `5` in group1 and the first `4` in group2.

Here is a code example extracting the data-length and type of message:

```
import re

line = "&5:420:0:03713031464@"

matchObj = re.match( r'\&(\d):(\d)', line)

if matchObj:
   print ("Data length : " + matchObj.group(1))
   print ("Type of message : " + matchObj.group(2))
```

You can use https://regex101.com/ to try your regular expression. It will also give you explanation of the search pattern, for example my example https://regex101.com/r/tSPciD/1

I will leave the rest to you to try to figure out how to parse the full string.